# Does it make sense to maximize both training and validation accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

While training my CNNs I usually aim to maximize the **validation** accuracy to 1.0 (i.e. 100%). I know that on the other hand it would not make much sense to aim for a **training** accuracy of 1.0, because we don't want our model to memorize the training data itself.

However, what about a "mixed" approach --
wouldn't it make sense to maximize both training and validation accuracy?

Comment: What do you mean? During each training iteration only training data accuracy is being maximied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first address what the purpose of validation is:

When we're training a neural net, we are trying to teach the neural net to perform well at a given task for the entire population of input/output pairs in the task. However, it is unrealistic to have the entire dataset, especially for high dimensional inputs such as images. Therefore, we create a **training** dataset that contains a (hopefully) large amount of that data. We **hope** when we're training a neural net that by maximizing performance on the training dataset, we maximize performance on the entire dataset. This is called **generalization**.

How do we know that the neural net is generalizing well? As you mentioned, we don't want to simply memorize the training data. That is where validation accuracy comes in. We feed data that the neural net did not train on through the network to evaluate its performance. Therefore, the purpose of the validations set is to measure the generalization.

You should watch both the training and validation accuracy. The difference between the validation and training accuracy is called the **generalization gap**, which will tell you how well your neural net is generalizing to new inputs. You want both the training and validation accuracy to be high, and the difference between them to be minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you could do so, that would be awesome, you wouldn't say a model is over fitting unless there is a gap between validation accuracy and training accuracy, if their values are close, both high or both low, then the model is not over fitting. ideally you want high accuracy on all samples, training, validation and testing, but as I said "IDEALLY". you just don't care as much about training samples.